# Usability problems with empty tables

Tags: html, usability, user-experience

I have a question about web usability related with tables, this is my use case:

I have a view with more than 1 table, I mean, I have **N>0 tables in the view** and each table has a title (for example "Photo list", "Video list", "Sound list").

Using javascript, users have the possibility **to change the "view level"**, I mean, the detail level of the view. This means that clicking in different action buttons (basic, medium, advance view) **the users can modify the amount of rows in each table**. So, could be that some of the **tables would be empty** (no rows).

My question: What is the best usability practice to manage empty tables?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Anyway: do not hide empty tables, things that appears and disappears are disorienting and they may don't understand why on earth the table they're looking for isn't there. Much better to keep empty tables with an informative muted row that says something like "no records to show for this view level". On UX you'll get much more detailed answers (I remember I read some articles about this but references are lost in memory)

Answer (score -1):

When you have identified tables that shows certain information you shouldn't hide then when they are empty, at least not without showing in any way that there's no data related to the empty table.

If you don't show the table maybe your users don't perceive that there is an entity of data that's empty, if you show it they will. This is important.

It could, however, be less important depending on the way you are showing your data. Let's say, for example, that your view shows on top a list of the different data types with the number of records in each one. If you keep a reminder there that X data type has 0 records, you can hide the table header on the view body, as all the info your user need is on the view.

On the contrary, if your users have no way to know that a specific data type is empty other than seeing an empty table, you need to keep it in your view to avoid them loosing information.

Keep in mind that information is the key on our world. Design is important to help and improve user experience, but you shouldn't put it before information.